# Check the expire date of every rows

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'll try to explain my problem:

I have one model `Attorney` with have many rows.
Every attorney have a date to expire in a date coloumn. Ex: 15/09/2013

I need to check, every day, if some attorney will expire in 30 days.

In other words, I need to check, every day, the date of every attorney registered and if the date of expire is less than 30 days, and grab the id of the attorney in this situation and execute an action.

I have nothing. How I do this?

Comment: have you looked into cron ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to use a [cron job](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html) to execute these task every day.

To check if a record will expire in 30 days, you could use php strtotime to calc the final date. Then, you should compare if the expire date is lower or equals:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime( date('Y-m-d') . ' +30 day' ));
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I'll see the cron. My problem with the operation is the 'foreach'. The compairs of dates is fine!

Comment: Well, as far as I get, I think you do not need to "foreach" anything. In fact, thinking in performance you should not do that. You just need to update the records filtering by date. You could use CakePHP [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) with that condition.

Answer (score 1):

try the cron job  for linux ;or schedule for windows . they will check the date field and do an action depend on your conditions ,  here is a link for example  :

http://blog.nexcess.net/2013/05/09/cron-job-for-the-last-day-of-the-month/